# Light House: Manifest's short_name will be truncated when displayed on homescreen

Tags: reactjs, lighthouse

I am not getting this. where we need to add short name in react project.

Make the short_name property in your Web App Manifest less than 12 characters.

{
  ...
  "short_name": "Air Horner",
  ...
}

Comment: I've seen the same warning on a webpage that does not even have a manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to the public\manifest.json file

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/

Comment: actully i am working with react. there is no head in react project.

Comment: ah, of course. sorry. you need to put it in the public/manifest.json for react.

Comment: sir i implement that think but its not working properly